# Find and combine results from two columns based on same search criteria

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am setting up a staff database and some of the staff have split roles across two teams in the same department. I am using the `QUERY` function on the Dashboard tab to bring up details for various teams, searching via manager or team. The problem I have is when trying to factor in the split roles into the searches.

For example, an employee who works part-time in one team and part-time in another will be listed under two managers and two teams in the main database. See image below:

[image: Table]

What I want it to come up with is as follows when you search for either Manager or Team:

Staff Member - Hours - Role

Person 1 - - - - 37 - - A

Person 2 - - - - 37 - - A

Person 4 - - - - 10 - - B

So all the people who work for a certain manager, whether the role is 1 or role 2 would be shown.

I have tried the following to combine the two column results:

```
={query(StaffData2,"select B,AT where K = '"&Dashboard!O8 &"' and AT is not null",1);query(StaffData2,"select B,AU where AO = '"&Dashboard!O8&"' and AU is not null",0)}
```

It seems to half work when the employee in a team does have a split role but it adds them as another entry on to the bottom of the results eg:

```
Person 1

Person 2

Person 1
```

Alternatively, if there are no split roles then the result comes back with an `ARRAY LATERAL` error.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Here is the test sheet I have made

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UgvleNMANr8VX90qmtgtLNd1BdwdvfOV3B5C4dAwDbA/edit?usp=sharing

Looking at it now I can see why the 'array lateral' error is happening though not sure how to fix that.

You should be able to see the formula works, kind of, but adds any people who work two roles for one manager as a separate entry on the list rather than combining them. So person '4' and '5' have been added twice on the current list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper way would be:

```
=QUERY({B3:E13; B3:B13, F3:H13}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col4 where Col3 = '"&C16&"'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: Brilliant thank you. To check I understand it.

The array at the beginning combines the the first role details, then the names with the second role details into the same data set rather than trying to combine two separate queries?

Comment: Oh one more thing, there is still the problem when a person works in different roles for the same manager. Is there a way of combining their hours for each role?

So if the person has job A and B for manager A could the two roles hours be combined?

Comment: yes and yes. see your sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1xSY.png

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful